# Replace certain text automatically with an image

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm currently creating a small website and I want to automatically replace certain text with an image **without** a press of a button. I want it done automatically, but I can't seem to make it work. Thank you!

Here's my code:

html

```
<p id="test">http://localhost:1111/</p>
```

javascript:

```
<script>
var str = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("http://localhost:1111", Element.innerHTML = "<img 
src='https://www.stockgumshoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/test.jpg");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
</script>
```

Comment: Did you intend to use two different element IDs (`test` and `demo`), or did you mean to use the same element ID so you are actually doing a replacement?

Comment: Ohhh. I've must have left the demo ID there by mistake. I tested to see if this worked with a button before. But i've decided I wanted to do this automatically without a press of a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this code you don't need any `id` or `class`

```
const paragraphs = document.querySelectorAll('p')

paragraphs.forEach((paragraph) => {
  if (paragraph.innerText == 'http://localhost:1111/') {
    return (paragraph.innerHTML = `
    <img src='https://www.stockgumshoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/test.jpg' />
    `)
  }
})
```

Comment: It works and I see the image but I can't use a class or id in project. Is there anyway you can do this with out finding the id or class with javascript, by finding the text?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<script>
var str = document.getElementById("test").innerHTML; 
var res = str.replace("http://localhost:1111", lement.innerHTML = "<img 
src='https://www.stockgumshoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/test.jpg");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
</script>
```

Try This:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = `<img 
src="https://www.stockgumshoe.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/test.jpg" />`;
</script>
```

Comment: Can you try the edited code? as far as using text to locate an element, it's possible.
`var element = $( "p:contains('http://localhost:1111')" )` would give you the element containing "http://localhost:1111'"

Comment: Hi, this does now work but.. can I do this without an ID or class? meaning can I just find the text with javascript and replace it?